# How to get the proportion of each tag value correponding to each `user_id`

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I get a dataframe as follows:

```
    user_id label
0   937922  1
1   937922  2
2   937922  2
3   937922  2
4   1369473 1
5   1330642 2
6   1330642 2
7   1330642 1
8   1330642 1
9   411741  1
10  411741  1
11  1552476 2
12  1552476 1
13  1552476 1
... ...
... ...
```

I want to get the proportion that `label` is `2` corresponding to each `user_id`, which should be like follows:

```
user_id label
937922  0.7500
1369473 0
1330642 0.5000
411741  0
1552476 0.3333
```

I know I should use `pd.groupby` somehow and divide it by `pd.groubpy(['user_id']).count()[['type']]`.
But it is hard to me to make it and I can't search what I want.
If not mind could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` and `value_counts` give you all counts:

```
df.groupby('user_id').label.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
user_id  label
411741   1        1.000000
937922   2        0.750000
         1        0.250000
1330642  1        0.500000
         2        0.500000
1369473  1        1.000000
1552476  1        0.666667
         2        0.333333
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

I will do `groupby` + `mean`

```
df.label.eq(2).groupby(df.user_id).mean()
user_id
411741     0.000000
937922     0.750000
1330642    0.500000
1369473    0.000000
1552476    0.333333
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) as:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['user_id'],df['label'], normalize='index').reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print(df)
       user_id         1         2
0       411741  1.000000  0.000000
1       937922  0.250000  0.750000
2      1330642  0.500000  0.500000
3      1369473  1.000000  0.000000
4      1552476  0.666667  0.333333
```